# How to auto login after Signup in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

signup & login mechanism (Different routes for signup and login)
On auto login after signup
On using an online backend service to store the data

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in more than one way
Like when user login you create a token and save it in cookie and when this token saved and valid in your cookie the client route user direct to dashboard if this token expired or invalid or not found client route the user to login page.
json web token will help you a lot in this

Comment: can you help with this token thing?

Comment: you can read docs from here
https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme